# When can a "cd" command fail in a shell script and what can I do to remedy it?

Tags: shell-script, command, cd-command, pwd

I have a shell script that failed to finish last week; it was a failed "`cd`" command and it exits if it fails.

The script is a `bash` shell script for configuring new Debian installs.
Here is the full script: [debianConfigAswome.sh](https://pastebin.com/6YVgNP9i). The script is run as root so it has full access to the file-system.

Can you please list all the reasons a script would not be able to successfully execute a `cd` command and what to do to avoid the error?

Comment: cd will output an error message when it fails. What did it say in your case?

Comment: If the user doesn't have the search permission on any directory component in the path then it will fail

Comment: You may want to look at the ERRORS section of `chdir(2)` to see what kind of things can go wrong when a process tries to change working directories

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I didn't have time to investigate when it happened and it was my fathers computer so I don't have it here

Comment: @muru that was my first thought too, but it isn't a file. It's a directory created by the `git clone` command.

Comment: @terdon nevermind, I just noticed the clone. But the clone is to the current directory, and the `cd` is to `$WORK_DIR/nanorc`. Odd path?

Comment: @somethingSomething what error message did you get? Your script has a lot of debugging info (good!), so which of the two `cd` commands you have failed? And are you sure it was the `cd` command and not the `chmod` command? Your script has a bug described in my answer, so I would expect the `chmod` to fail before the `cd`.

Comment: @terdon Sorry about the not having time for error handling and debugging but I'm sure it was the first, when it was down to setting nano up it failed and I got the echo that cd failed, thank you for the answer `terdon`..... I added the chmod today, so after I had the `cd` fail

Comment: @somethingSomething oh, there you go then: the git command created the directory under your current dir, not under `$WORK_DIR`. So just add a `cd "$WORK_DIR"` before the `git` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are various reasons why a `cd` could fail. The target might not exist, the target might not be a directory, you might not have permission to access the target directory, `cd` might not be found (although this is extremely unlikely since it's a shell builtin), the `chdir()` operation might fail due to a broken file system etc.

In this particular case, however, it looks like a bug in the script. The script you link to has two calls to `cd`:

```
cd "$WORK_DIR"/nanorc || { echo "cd failed"; exit 127; }
```

and

```
cd $HOME || { echo "cd $HOME failed"; exit 155; }
```

I am assuming the one that failed is the first one, since `cd $HOME` should normally work. This is the relevant (slightly simplified) section of your script:

```
if [ ! -d "$WORK_DIR"/nanorc  ]
then
    echo "Setting up Nanorc file for all users....please, wait!"
    git clone https://$OAUTH_TOKEN:x-auth-basic@github.com/gnihtemoSgnihtemos/nanorc || { echo "git failed"; exit 127; }
    chmod 755 "$WORK_DIR"/nanorc || { echo "chmod nanorc failed"; exit 127; }
     cd "$WORK_DIR"/nanorc || { echo "cd failed"; exit 127; }
fi
```

So, if  `"$WORK_DIR"/nanorc` is not a directory, you run a `git` command which creates the `nanorc` directory. The first possible issue is that the `nanorc` will be created in the current directory which might not be `$WORK_DIR`. At this point in your script, you haven't actually moved to `$WORK_DIR`, so it should only work if you run the script from within `$WORK_DIR`.

So the simple solution is to add a `cd $WORK_DIR` before the `git` command:

```
if [ ! -d "$WORK_DIR"/nanorc  ]
then
    cd "$WORK_DIR" | { echo "cd $WORK_DIR failed"; exit 127; }
    echo "Setting up Nanorc file for all users....please, wait!"
    git clone https://$OAUTH_TOKEN:x-auth-basic@github.com/gnihtemoSgnihtemos/nanorc || { echo "git failed"; exit 127; }
    chmod 755 "$WORK_DIR"/nanorc || { echo "chmod nanorc failed"; exit 127; }
     cd "$WORK_DIR"/nanorc || { echo "cd failed"; exit 127; }
fi
```

Comment: Another possibility was my first guess: there is a `nanorc` file in `$WORK_DIR`, `git clone` made a directory in the current directory (!= `$WORK_DIR`), `chmod` succeeded on `$PWD/nanorc` the file but `cd` failed. Everything succeeds up till the `cd`.

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. But the OP [apparently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/511867/when-can-a-cd-command-fail-in-a-shell-script-and-what-can-i-do-to-remidiy-it?noredirect=1#comment946536_511867) added the `chmod` after getting the error in this case.